# iOS - Facebook SDK v3.11.1 - change default app id

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I m using facebook SDK v3.11.1, and I have 2 facebook applications (on facebbok), each one has app ID.

I change the default app ID programmatically:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:<my_app_id>];
```

and then I invoke `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions`, the facebook ask for permission to the relevant application.

After that i try to change the default app ID (same code as above) at the same session, and the facebook doesn't ask or permissions.

Should I close the old session, change the default app ID and reopen a new session?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FBSession object is used to authenticate a user and manage the user's session. After initializing a FBSession object the Facebook App ID and desired permissions are stored. Opening the session will initiate the authentication flow after which a valid user session should be available and subsequently cached. Closing the session can optionally clear the cache.
If an request requires user authorization then an FBSession object should be used.

**appID**

Identifies the Facebook app which the session object represents.
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *appID;

[more](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/)